# Why when i add data to firebase, the data keep looping?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter and firebase and I do not know why when I upload any data to firebase the data will keep repeating the same thing but when I hot restart the upload item back to 1, this is my code:

```
Future getDocId() async {
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .orderBy('mobile', descending: true)
    .get()
    .then(
      (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (document) {
          print(document.reference);
          docIDs.add(document.reference.id);
        },
      ),
    );
```

}

```
body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getDocId(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: docIDs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: ReadUser(documentId: docIDs[index]),
                      tileColor: Colors.purple[100],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

This is my future builder

```
 return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data =
          snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Text('Name:' +
          '${data['name']}' +
          "\n"
              'Email:' +
          '${data['email']}' +
          "\n"
              'Mobile Number:' +
          '+' +
          '${data['mobile']}' +
          "");
    }
    return Text('Loading..');
  }),
);
```

Comment: could you include the part that you are using this data and show it?

Comment: Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getDocId(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: docIDs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index)

Comment: could you Update your question and add there?

Comment: @MasterHarith Instead of adding code in a comment, click the `edit` link right under your question to add it there. That also allows you to use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up, so that it becomes more readable

Comment: done, mb im still learning using stack overflow

Comment: could you also include the part that you upload things? @MasterHarith

Comment: are you add the full code of `getDocId`? you aren't return any thing in `getDocId`?  @MasterHarith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you are fetching your data is wrong, instead of pass the result into outside variable you need to return it like this, I assume docIDs is a list of string:

```
Future<List<String>> getDocId() async {
    try {
      var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .orderBy('mobile', descending: true)
          .get();
      return snapshot.docs.map((document) => document.reference.id).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

then change your `FutureBuilder` to this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
  future: getDocId(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Loading....');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          List<String> data = snapshot.data ?? [];
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: ReadUser(documentId: data[index]),
                  tileColor: Colors.purple[100],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: @MasterHarith was it what you want?